# How does v-bind:style work to modify width css property?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

The code below does not produce any style for my div, but the attribute questionOption.visualBox.width is printed inside the div just fine, what am I doing wrong?

```
<div
    v-for="(questionOption, index) in questionOptions"
    v-bind:key="index"
    class="annotation"
    v-bind:style="{width: questionOption.visualBox.width}"
  >{{questionOption.label}}{{questionOption.visualBox.width}}</div>
```

Comment: `questionOption.visualBox.width+"px"` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you need to write the unit of the width. With your currently code it will produce a css that look like this :

```
{
    ...
    width: 34
    ...
}
```

It will not produce visual effects.

For this reason you need to add a unit (.e.g : %, px). For instance if you want `px` you have to write :

```
<div
    v-for="(questionOption, index) in questionOptions"
    v-bind:key="index"
    class="annotation"
    v-bind:style="{width: questionOption.visualBox.width + 'px'}"
  >{{questionOption.label}}{{questionOption.visualBox.width}}</div>
```

Comment: Hhm, I will try later, but shouldn’t it show the inline CSS without unit in my inspector? Because it is not showing any style tag on the div when I inspect my page...